# asp.net task wont stay running on Amazon EC2

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-ec2, docker

I followed this tutorial: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/11/26/asp-net-5-on-aws-ec2-container-service-in-10-steps/

I created a simple helloworld asp.net 5 web application. I then created a Docker image and pushed it to Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/jacobreid/helloworld/

I then created an Amazon EC2 cluster using my Docker image and the task won't stay running.

If I look at the task it says the stopped reason is : Essential container in task exited.

I am very new to EC2 and Docker so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to run your image locally? Running your image I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: I get that error too, I got a new container to work how do I turn that container into an image that I can push to Docker Hub to replace my current image?

Comment: I updated my image on Docker Hub and now instead of Stopped the task status is pending. How do I find out why it's pending?

Comment: It changed  from pending to running but when I browse to my instance, it never loads.